MorphologicalGraph returning different graphs for visually indistinguishable images
I am using MorphologicalGraph on two images, which are visually indistinguishable, but the resulting graphs are different.
Clear["`*"];
im = ...;
MorphologicalGraph[Binarize@ColorNegate@im, VertexLabels -> Automatic]

The picture im is this:

The same picture is inconsistent with the node diagram obtained by running the code twice:

To be more specific: the first run of the code above uses this image:

The second run of the code uses this image:

Is there no difference in appearance, or are they different in nature?


At first we make the three pictures become more thick by RegionDilation.

img1 = Import["https://i.sstatic.net/5nOoGjHO.png"];
img2 = Import["https://i.sstatic.net/7A12xNXe.png"];
img3 = Import["https://i.sstatic.net/CF1onQrk.png"];
f = ColorNegate@
    Graphics@RegionDilation[ImageMesh@Binarize@ColorNegate@#, 10] &;
results = f /@ {img1, img2, img3}
MorphologicalGraph /@ results


